# error in storing value of a text_input in variable in php

Tags: php, session, variables

I have 2 pages:

1. send.php
2. confirm.php

In send.php I have an input text_box for entering a number(ex:12345) by enduser(this number is private key in database).Next I want to store the entered number(12345) in a session. In page2 I want to read that number(12345) from session and use to select rows from database.But I get an error:

Notice: Undefined index: nid in C:\xampp\htdocssend.php on line 4

```
<?php
include "db.php";
session_start();
$nid=$_POST["nid"];
$_SESSION['user_id']=$nid;
//$_SESSION['nid']=True;
if(isset($_POST['nid'])){
header("Location: confirm2.php");

exit;
}
<form action="send.php" method="post">

<div class="top-row">
<div class="field-wrap">
<label>
your id<span class="req">*</span>
</label>
<input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name="nid" />
</div>
<button type="submit" class="button button-block"/>submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the send.php code? sorry  I see that this is the send. But the post? Where does that come from

Comment: use print_r($_POST) at start of script  and check is "nid" is set in it or not

Comment: @Andreas i add the rest of send.php code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move
`$nid=$_POST["nid"];
$_SESSION['user_id']=$nid;`
into the
`if(isset($_POST['nid'])){` block.
As you were trying to use `$_POST["nid"]` before it existed. You'll get the value in `$_POST["nid"]` only after the form submission.
And also change `if(isset($_POST['nid']))` to `if(isset($_POST['nid']) && $_POST['nid'] != '')`